# SQL Server : query if table exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) over () as countNum,
    [F1] AS STANDARDandOBJ, 
    [F2] AS CLUSTER,
    [F3] AS OBJECTIVE,
    [F4] AS EXTRA0 
     IF COL_LENGTH([tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Blahsing$'], [F5]) IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN 
           print 'exists' 
        END 
     ELSE 
        BEGIN 
           print 'Nope'
        END,
    CONCAT([F1], [F2]) AS combined 
FROM 
    [tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Blahsing$'] 
WHERE 
    LOWER(F3) NOT LIKE 'course tools-%'
```

But it seems that I have an error of:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Which is pointing to row:

```
 ,CONCAT([F1], [F2]) AS combined
```

How does this need to be formatted in order to work?

Comment: You cann't use `IF` in `SELECT` statement, also the same for `print `

Comment: **Reason for the downvote as it's pointless to randomly do that without explanation as to why.** This is a help forum not an *I can't believe you didn't know that" forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `IF` inside a `SELECT`, you need a `CASE` expression. Also, it doesn't make sense to use `PRINT` inside a column:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) over () as countNum 
     ,[F1] AS STANDARDandOBJ 
     ,[F2] AS CLUSTER 
     ,[F3] AS OBJECTIVE 
     ,[F4] AS EXTRA0 
     ,CASE 
        WHEN COL_LENGTH('[tmpExcelDB].[dbo].[''Blahsing$'']', '[F5]') IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 'exists'
        ELSE 'Nope'
      END
     ,CONCAT([F1], [F2]) AS combined 
  FROM [tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Blahsing$'] 
  WHERE 
     LOWER(F3) NOT LIKE 'course tools-%';
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Lamak!

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. [IF...ELSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) is not supported in a select list, use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) instead
2. [PRINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) is not supported in a select list, just the literal string value is needed

See the [CASE Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) for a relevant example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) over () as countNum 
     ,[F1] AS STANDARDandOBJ 
     ,[F2] AS CLUSTER 
     ,[F3] AS OBJECTIVE 
     ,[F4] AS EXTRA0 ,
    ( CASE When COL_LENGTH([tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Blahsing$'], [F5]) IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 
            'exists'             
     ELSE            
            'Nope'
        END),

     CONCAT([F1], [F2]) AS combined 
  FROM [tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['0812 Orientation to Nursing$'] 
  WHERE  LOWER(F3)NOT LIKE 'course tools-%'
```